# datastax solr index no documents

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I have a datastax cluster setup, and am trying to run through the demo located here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutStrt.html.  The cluster is healthy, with 2 datacenters (2 cassandra nodes in one dc and 1 solr node in another dc).  The issue i'm seeing is that the solr admin is reporting no documents, even though there are records in cassandra.   Any ideas on what to look at to see why nothing is indexing?

Note: I've tried issuing a reindex from the solr core admin page and it runs without error, but there are no documents.

Comment: Can you confirm your version is really 4.6?

Comment: When you create your core, did you say reindex=true?

Comment: Yes I can confirm its 4.6, and yes I've tried full reindex on the solr core as well.